# Line numbers with logback

Tags: java, logback

I want to add line numbers (just a sequential integer that keeps incrementing on each log line) to my logback config - how do I do that? I looked through the properties available in the [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) but i couldn't see it anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: I agree with Peter Lawrey on both counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter mentioned, writing a [custom conversion specifier](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier) is your best option at the moment (June 2012). Here is sample code:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter ;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class LocalSequenceNumberConverter extends ClassicConverter {

  AtomicLong sequenceNumber = new AtomicLong(0);

  @Override
  public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return Long.toString(sequenceNumber.getAndIncrement());
  }
}
```

Please post on the logback-user mailing if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting JSON, you can use the [SequenceJsonProvider](https://javadoc.io/static/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder/7.1.1/net/logstash/logback/composite/loggingevent/SequenceJsonProvider.html) to add the field `sequence`.

> Outputs an incrementing sequence number. Useful for determining if log events get lost along the transport chain.

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.SequenceJsonProvider"/>
</encoder>
```